# Create image CSS transition when chaging source url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

I have an image that when it gets clicked changes the source url and displays a different image, i want to play a transition that will animate the size change of the image.

Starting HTML

```
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DN1kd3vXkAE9UR-.jpg" class="selected-image" />
```

On click the img source will change, to a different size image.

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
.selected-image{
   transition: all 1s;
}
```

Here is my example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zfvrczs5/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you looking for resizing use the animate and put the value you need

```
$(".selected-image").on("click", function () {
    var image = "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DN9MWb5WsAAaYYR.jpg";

    $(this).animate({ width: 1000, height:700 }, "slow", function(){
       $(this).attr("src", image);
    });
});
```

Comment: I need it to support different sizes.

Comment: you can change the values as you wish

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`. You can change the numbers (in ms) to what you need.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/sq0x02jk/1/)

```js
$(".selected-image").on("click", function() {
  let image = "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DN9MWb5WsAAaYYR.jpg";

  $(this).fadeOut(700, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', image);
    })
    .fadeIn(700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DN1kd3vXkAE9UR-.jpg" class="selected-image" />

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, i want a resizing transition

Comment: @axebau24 I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the current image to stretch to the next image while transitioning?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8104910/5561605